# Is there a Material Difference between Fermwraps and Non-Branded fermwraps?

Tags: temperature-control, fermwrap

[Here](https://www.google.com/#q=fermwrap&tbm=shop&spd=17540634272955716106) is a "Carboy Heater" from Adventures in Homebrewing.

[Here](https://www.google.com/#q=fermwrap&tbm=shop&spd=4394287302096737472) is an "Electric Fermentation Heater" from Northern Brewer.

I just learned yesterday that "Fermwrap" is a product from MoreBeer. Looking at the pictures, the Fermwrap looks identical to the non branded products, but I've been able to find the non branded products cheaper than the Fermwrap.

I went ahead and bought more Fermwraps just to be consistent with my previous purchases.

However, are they perfect substitutes for each other, or is one superior? Has anyone tried both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And [Here is Flex-Watt Heat Tape](http://www.bigappleherp.com/Flex-Watt-Heat-Tape), as used in herpological applications.

They are all exactly the same stuff, the homebrew products are just cut to fit carboys and pre-assembled. It's just a big resistive element, really.

Comment: Why am I paying $25-33 for a Fermwrap that doesn't wrap around the carboy fully when I can make it my self? Great find! Thanks.